# How to Simplify :$\frac{32^3}{2} \times {8^5} \times \frac{2^{-5}}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not sure how to simplify with different bases.

$$32^{\frac{3}{2}} \times {8^5} \times \frac{2^{-5}}{2}$$

Comment: Add MathJax please?

Comment: I have seen a 3 different edits in the last 4 minutes.  I think the OP needs to clarify his question.

Comment: Do you mean $32^{\frac{3}{2}}*8^5*2^{\frac{-5}{2}}$

Comment: How is this "complex"? I always thought that complex multiplication referred to products involving imaginary elements.

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP means
$$(32^{\frac{3}{2}}) ({8^5})(2^{\frac{-5}{2}})$$
$$32^{3/2}=(2^5)^{3/2}=2^{15/2}$$
$$(8^{5})=(2^3)^{5}=2^{15}$$
then use
$$2^a.2^b.2^c=2^{a+b+c}$$

Comment: its supposed to be 32^3/2

Comment: $\frac{32^3}{2}=\frac{2^{15}}{2}=2^{15-1}=2^{14}$

Comment: im not sure how to input it, but 32 is to the power of 3/2

Comment: @BillSmith if you look at the edits, you know the mathjax behind it :)